# ViewModel is destroyed after lock and unlock phone

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I have a Fragment where I lock my screen , the view still populated, when I unlock the phone and press on a button the app crashes since the viewModel is recreated, how can I fix this ?

I create the instance this way

```
private val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel by viewModels()
```

Why the data is not retained after I unlock the phone ?

Comment: I don't know why it's not retained, but the destruction of ViewModels is usually handled with SavedStateHandle. In any case, it's important you handle the saving of the state since it will happen for a variety of reasons other than what you have here.

Comment: How you could retain this with the proposed solution ? can you give me an answer or hint ? thanks

Comment: [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate), and [example usage](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/cfb5ac6ea6a5c888b171d88d7ea4287a33af5cb9/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks/TasksViewModel.kt#L45).